# Get closer turtles

Tags: netlogo

I'm using netlogo 6.0.4, and I want to get the closer turtles from a turtle.

I using this code:

```
      create-players 1[
        set color red
        set size 5  
        set the-player self     
        set team "red"   
      ]
        create-balls 1 [
        set color orange
        set size 2.5
        set the-ball self   
        ] 
       to-report get-players-close-to-ball   
       report players with [distance the-ball <= 1] 
       end
```

but I get as output (agentset, 0 turtles) that I can't compare to self like this:

```
to-report decision-steal-ball 
  let decision 0
  if (self = get-players-close-to-ball)[
    set decision 10
  ]
  report decision
end
```

.
So I try to use :

```
to-report get-players-closer-to-the-ball
  report the-player with [distance the-ball <= 1]
end
```

But I am getting this error:
"WITH expected input to be an agentset but got the turtle (player 10) instead."

So the question is : how to get the players closer to the ball?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first code has `to-report` inside a procedure and will generate an error before even trying to steal the ball. You also have a conceptual problem - there could be any number of players close to the ball. The message is telling you that there were no players close to the ball on that occasion.

NetLogo is returning an agentset with all the players that are close to the ball. An agentset cannot be tested like 'if self = agentset'. What you need is `if member? self get-players-close-to-ball` and that will check if self is a member of the agentset. Even better, it works even if the agentset is empty, so you don't have to do a test `if any?` first.

Comment: sorry I posted a very bad example removing part of significant code. Ok I understand your answer, but I have another questions: how can I get the element of the agenset list? Sorry but I am really new to netlogo. Thank you

Comment: And why If I print  print (member? self get-players-close-to-ball) I got  distance the-ball ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'get the element of the agentset'. What agent are you trying to get? I think this is probably a separate question and you should do a new question specifically about that (with the relevant code)

Comment: like which players

Comment: You could do something like `ask get-players-close-to-ball [type self]` and you will get a list in the command center output. Or `ask get-players-close-to-ball [set color red]` if you want to show them on the screen (and then get all the others to turn blue)